# How to make the OSX text substitution available everywhere?

Tags: macos, keyboard, text-input

As it currently stands, the OSX text substitution feature seems to require an application to actively support it to be available - which many do not.

Is there a way to make the text substitution available everywhere? If I'm not wrong this should be possible, I am thinking of a program that achieves this by doing something like hooking into the keyboard input on system level and performs the substitution by sending additional keystrokes after detecting that a shortcut has been entered. (E.g. after entering (c) it sends three delete keycodes followed by the substitution.) However I didn't find anything like this through my Google searches.

I'd also be content with a solution that requires me to select the text-to-replace and hit a keyboard shortcut to perform the action.

Does a program like this exist, or is there any other way?

Comment: You can use app like TextExpander.

Answer (score 1):

You could try any of these:

1. [TextExpander](https://smilesoftware.com/textexpander)
2. [Atext](https://www.trankynam.com/atext/)
3. [Typinator](http://alternativeto.net/software/atext/)